# NuGet 2.2.3 extention problems. Cannot connect to server?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget, nuget-server

I have project where NugGet is used.

I am trying to build project and i have next errors:

```
    ...

Error   88  Unable to find version '2.1.505.2' of package 'Unity'.  Common

Error   84  Unable to find version '1.0' of package 'CommonServiceLocator'. Common


Error   90  The command ""D:\Development\root\.nuget\nuget.exe" install "D:\Development\root\Common\packages.config" -source ""  -RequireConsent -solutionDir "D:\Development\root\ "" exited with code 1.  common
```

Also i get error when trying to download packages in NuGet package manager.

**An error occurred while trying to restore packages. Please try again**
[image]

Default visual studio online extensions search is working without problems!

I am not using proxy:

[image]

VS 2012 is running under admin rights.

Also visual studio config was modified:

```
<system.net>
<defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" enabled="true">
<proxy usesystemdefault="True"/>
</defaultProxy>
<settings>
<servicePointManager expect100Continue="false" />
<ipv6 enabled="true"/>
</settings>
</system.net>
```

But this is doesnot helps.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found problem. Source for NuGet was not set by default in visual studio 2012.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem but found that it was a glitch with the NuGet package manager. Although my package sources were defined (the default nuget.org and an internal nuget gallery), I had to de-select, click 'OK', then reopen and select the sources again.
After doing so the 'restore missing packages' option succeeded. This was a very frustrating glitch and oddly only affected one of my VS2010 solutions!

Comment: This workaround worked for me in VS2012. Odd behavior, but it seems to be fine now.

Comment: I did the same thing but after de-selecting all the packages, when i reselected all of them again, it gave the same error. But when i selected only "https://nuget.org/api/v2/", then it worked fine. So looks like there was a conflict between the various package sources that i had configured

Answer (score 0):

In package repository does not exists one/many of project requiring packages.
We have local nuget repository and after getting project to new PC it was impossible to restore missing packages, because they was old and only newer version of those packages where exists in repository.