# Error on Installing or Updating via the nuget.org server

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget

I am getting a 404 for updating or installing Nuget packages from this url

http://nuget.org/api/v2/

This is fairly recent. It first happened right I installed the latest 2012.2 update. I uninstalled it. but still having the same issues.  These other questions on here get the same error but they all involve a custom hosted server not nuget.org.

[NuGet - Installing Individual Packages reporting "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407799/nuget-installing-individual-packages-reporting-the-remote-server-returned-an?rq=1)
and
[NuGet 2.2.3 extention problems. Cannot connect to server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14689747/nuget-2-2-3-extention-problems-cannot-connect-to-server)
on a different machine vista with vs2010 this is the error i get
Successfully installed 'jQuery 1.9.1'.
Executing script file 'C:\Development\XXXXMVC2\packages\jQuery.1.8.3\Tools\uninstall.ps1'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Access to the path 'C:\Development\XXXXMVC2\packages.config' is denied.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the issue is the TFS server is down.  I know this because when I work with in another directory out side the workspace it is fine. uggh. now then how do you work with TFS in your local workspace when it is down